# horizontal slider a la gmail

Tags: android, android-layout, gmail, android-tablelayout

I see that the latest version of GMail has a slider. Basically, I can slide an entry to reveal what's behind it. I have been needing to do the same thing. I have tried to use onTouch to track displacement, etc. But my approach is very jiggery and the actual scrolling lags quite a bit. Does anyone know how to accomplish what I seek with horizontal scrollView or such? Or better yet, how GMail is doing theirs?

An important aspect of mine is to have some snap action. So if the user has scrolled to greater than X, I am to continue sliding to the left for her, for example, until the front image reaches the left edge.

Or could I use a navigation drawer to accomplish this? I don't think so as yet, but maybe someone has done it. I have been working on this for about a week now, and all my attempts are not quite there.

Comment: http://www.androidviews.net/2013/03/swipelistview/

Comment: Thanks for recommending SwipeListView. I am not using maven in my project. How do I use SwipeListView? Such as where are the jars, etc.

Comment: Ask the author of that library. I am not that author.

Comment: There's a link to snapshots on his GitHub page: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/com/fortysevendeg/android/swipelistview/1.0-SNAPSHOT/

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple Dev Bytes that discusses how to implement this from scratch (see "DevBytes: Animating ListView Deletion" and "DevBytes: Animating ListView Deletion: Now on Gingerbread!"). Alternatively, you could look at [SwipeListView](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/03/swipelistview/).

Comment: Thanks for recommending SwipeListView. I am not using maven in my project. How do I use SwipeListView? Such as where are the jars, etc.